# Dummit & Foote Chapter 1.2 Exercise 17 (Group Presentations)

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

The exercise is to show that if $n = 3k$, then the group presentation $\langle x, y \mid x^n = y^2 = 1,\ xy = yx^2 \rangle$ generates $D_6$. The group presentation for $D_6$ given in the book is $D_6 = \langle r, s \mid r^3 = y^2 = 1,\ rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$.

Now, my aim was to show first that $x^3 = 1$ and then that $x$ and $x^2$ are distinct. However, I'm having issues showing that $x \neq 1$, or equivalently that $x$ and $x^2$ are distinct elements. I know I somehow must use that $n = 3k$ since I didn't need it to show $x^3 = 1$. What confuses me is that I can set $x = y = 1$ and all the relations given in the original presentation would be satisfied.

Comment: You need to show that the presentation is *compatible* with $x\not=1$. That is, find concrete elements (say permutations of order 3, respectively 2) that can be plugged in for $x$ and $y$ so that the relations still hold. In fact you can choose WLOG $y=(1,2)$ and then just have to try which of the two possibilities for $x$ works.

Comment: But how does this compatibility rely on the fact that $n = 3k$?

Comment: Put $n=3$ and you have $x^2 = x^{-1}$, so your presentation is equivalent to the one in your book.

Comment: @Peatherfed if $n\not=3k$ then the relation $x^n=1$ will not be satisfied by $x=(1,2,3)$ or $x=(1,3,2)$.